# Replace date time with new timezone in PHP

Tags: php, string

I got string like:

```
[ 15.04.2012 15:48:03 ] blahblah
[ 17.02.2012 22:49:11 ] blahblah
[ 18.11.2011 10:11:39 ] blahblah
```

the date time is utc, how can I replace these date time strings with utc+8 date time?

Comment: have you tried date('format','datestring')

Comment: Why are you adding an integer? Shouldn't you be using a [named timezone](http://us.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)?

Comment: I agree with @webbiedave. Then you can use PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. Also, named timezones respect DST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the timezone is +0 and you want to change it to utc+8 why not just add 8 hours?

```
echo date('d.m.Y G:i:s', strtotime('+8 hours', strtotime('15.04.2012 15:48:03')));
// 15.04.2012 23:48:03
```

Comment: @meze utc+8 does not respect DST. Half the year I'm in utc-5 and the other half I'm in utc-4 but my timezone is always America/New_York

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about the local time

Comment: how to replace all these string in PHP with new time strings? Does php can do text process like awk?

Comment: @meze Ah, yes.. that would be a problem. However, I took OP's choice in words `utc+8` literally.

Comment: use date('I'); (capital i) to determine if the timezone is in daylight savings http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @timy [PHP has excellent documentation](http://php.net/). Check [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)

Comment: @ContextSwitch better use `$date = new DateTime('15.04.2012 15:48:03', new DateTimeZone('UTC')); $date->modify('+8 hours');`